# How to set RGB pixel in a BufferedImage to display a 16-bit-depth PNG?

Tags: java, rgb, pixel, bufferedimage, 16-bit

I am trying to read and show a PNG file.
I have no problem dealing with images with 8-bit depth.
I proceed as follow:

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Then I read the 3*8=24 bits of each pixel, save them in an array of byte `data` and put them in the image with:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
     result.setRGB(x, y, ((data[x * 3 + 0] & 0xff) << 16)
                       + ((data[x * 3 + 1] & 0xff) << 8)
                       + ((data[x * 3 + 2] & 0xff)));
```

The problem is now with 16-bit depth images. Of course `data` is bigger now and it contains 48bits, divided in 6 bytes, for each RGB triple: from the debugger `data` has the values I expect.
How can I set the RGB pixel? Do I have to change the BufferedImage declaration? Maybe with:

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
```

Many thanks in advance!

P.S.: following PNG standars, the image has color type 2 (RGB without alpha).

---

Maybe I'll have to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html

Answer (score 1):

@haraldK has pointed in the right direction. I'm providing some working code which is from "PNGReader" of "[icafe](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe)" Java image library.

```
if(bitsPerPixel == 16) {
    if(interlace_method==NON_INTERLACED)
       spixels = generate16BitRGBPixels(compr_data, false);
    else {
       spixels = generate16BitRGBInterlacedPixels(compr_data, false);
               }
    int[] off = {0, 1, 2}; //band offset, we have 3 bands
    int numOfBands = 3;
    boolean hasAlpha = false;
    int trans = Transparency.OPAQUE;
    int[] nBits = {16, 16, 16}; 
    if(alpha != null) { // Deal with single color transparency
       off = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3}; //band offset, we have 4 bands
       numOfBands = 4;
       hasAlpha = true;
       trans = Transparency.TRANSLUCENT;
       nBits = new int[] {16, 16, 16, 16};                      
    }
    db = new DataBufferUShort(spixels, spixels.length);
    raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(db, width, height, width*numOfBands, numOfBands, off, null);
    cm = new ComponentColorModel(colorSpace, nBits, hasAlpha, false, trans, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
}
return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, false, null);
```

Here is the generate16BitRGBPixels() method:

```
private short[] generate16BitRGBPixels(byte[] compr_data, boolean fullAlpha) throws Exception {
     //
     int bytesPerPixel = 0;
     byte[] pixBytes;

     if (fullAlpha)
         bytesPerPixel = 8;
     else 
         bytesPerPixel = 6;

     bytesPerScanLine = width*bytesPerPixel;         

     // Now inflate the data.
     pixBytes = new byte[height * bytesPerScanLine];

     // Wrap an InflaterInputStream with a bufferedInputStream to speed up reading
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compr_data)));

     apply_defilter(bis, pixBytes, height, bytesPerPixel, bytesPerScanLine);

     short[] spixels = null;

     if(alpha != null) { // Deal with single color transparency
         spixels = new short[width*height*4];
         short redMask = (short)((alpha[1]&0xff)|(alpha[0]&0xff)<<8);
         short greenMask = (short)((alpha[3]&0xff)|(alpha[2]&0xff)<<8);;
         short blueMask = (short)((alpha[5]&0xff)|(alpha[4]&0xff)<<8);

         for(int i = 0, index = 0; i < pixBytes.length; index += 4) {
             short red = (short)((pixBytes[i++]&0xff)<<8|(pixBytes[i++]&0xff));
             short green = (short)((pixBytes[i++]&0xff)<<8|(pixBytes[i++]&0xff));
             short blue = (short)((pixBytes[i++]&0xff)<<8|(pixBytes[i++]&0xff));
             spixels[index] = red;
             spixels[index + 1] = green;
             spixels[index + 2] = blue;
             if(spixels[index] == redMask && spixels[index + 1] == greenMask && spixels[index + 2] == blueMask) {
                 spixels[index + 3] = (short)0x0000;                               
             } else {
                 spixels[index + 3] = (short)0xffff;
             }
         }
     } else
         spixels = ArrayUtils.toShortArray(pixBytes, true);

     return spixels;         
 }
```

and the ArrayUtils.toShortArray() method:

```
public static short[] toShortArray(byte[] data, int offset, int len, boolean bigEndian) {

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data, offset, len);

    if (bigEndian) {
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    } else {
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    }

    ShortBuffer shortBuf = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
    short[] array = new short[shortBuf.remaining()];
    shortBuf.get(array);

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an image with 16 bits *per sample* (or 48 bits per pixel), there is no  `BufferedImage.TYPE_...` constant for that. `TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB` creates an image with 16 bits *per pixel*, with samples of 5 (red), 6 (green) and 5 (blue) bits respectively. I think these USHORT RGB values are leftovers from a time when some computes actually had the option of a 16 bit display (aka "Thousands of colors").

What you need to do, to actually create an image with 16 bits per sample, is:

```
ColorModel cm;
WritableRaster raster;

BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

The raster is created from a data buffer of type `DataBufferUShort` with either 3 banks and a `BandedSampleModel` with 3 bands, or use a single bank and a `PixelInterleavedSampleModel` with a `pixelStride` of 3, `scanLineStride` of 3 * `width` and `bandOffsets` `{0, 1, 2}`.

Here's a full sample, using interleaved sample model:

```
ColorSpace sRGB = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB)
ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(sRGB, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT, w, h, 3, null);
BufferedImage rgb = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

PS: With the data buffer exposed, you can access the `short` samples directly, to manipulate the pixels. This is much faster than using `BufferedImage.getRGB(...)/setRGB(...)`, and will keep the original 16 bit per sample precision. `BufferedImage.getRGB(...)` will convert the pixel values to 32 bit pixel/8 bit per sample, and thus lose the extra precision.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will study these classes and let you know.

Comment: I'm having problems in creating the ColorModel and the WritableRaster.
What kind of ColorModel do I have to use? ComponentColorModel or can I set it to null?
And how do I have to create the WritableRaster?
I used a `PixelInterleavedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 3, 3*img.getWidth(), bandOffset)` as you said.
Maybe the problems are in the DataBufferUShort that I pass to the method `createWritableRaster`.