# How to display a 48 bit RGB image (16 bit per channel) in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, rgb, bufferedimage, 16-bit

I'm using JavaFX and I have a 16bit grayscale image that I'm able to show with the following code:

```
public Image createNewImageFromArrayPixels(int[][] pixels) {        
        int width = pixels.length;
        int height = pixels[0].length;
        
        int[] buffer = from2DArrayTo1DArray(pixels);
        
        ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(
                ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), //we have grayscale images
                new int[]{16},                              //bit depth: 16 bit per pixel
                false,
                false,
                Transparency.OPAQUE,
                DataBuffer.TYPE_INT);                       //every pixel has an integer intensity
                
        WritableRaster raster = colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(height, width);
        DataBufferInt buff = (DataBufferInt) raster.getDataBuffer();
        
        int[] bufferData = buff.getData();
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, bufferData, 0, (buffer.length < bufferData.length ? buffer.length : bufferData.length));
        
        BufferedImage bm = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
        Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bm, null);
        
        return img;
    }
```

Now I want to transform it in a 48bit RGB image (16bit per channel), but I can't understand how.

At the moment I'm able to create a RGB 24bit image (8 bit per channel) by taking the int value of a pixel from the grayscale image and building manually the bytes that will compose the pixels with the following code:

```
private Image createRGBImageFromGrayPixels(int[][] pixels) {
        
        int width = pixels.length;
        int height = pixels[0].length;
        
        BufferedImage bm = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                
                int converted = from16to8(pixels[y][x]);
                
                System.out.println("original " + pixels[y][x] + " = " + converted + " = " + from8to16(converted));
                
                int rgb = converted;
                rgb = (rgb << 8) + converted; 
                rgb = (rgb << 8) + converted;
               
                bm.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }
        
        Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bm, null);
        
        return img;
    }

private int from16to8(int value) {
        
        int originalStart = 0;
        int originalEnd = 65535;
        
        int newStart = 0;
        int newEnd = 255; 
        
        double scale = (double)(newEnd - newStart) / (originalEnd - originalStart);
        double res = newStart + ((value - originalStart) * scale);
        System.out.println(res);
        int result = Math.round(Math.round(res));
        
        return result;
    }
```

Similarly, I'm also able to create the same structure for 16bits obtaining the desired rgb value, but it is a long and is not accepted by the setRGB() method, so I'm not able to create the bufferedImage, whose type I can't specify.

Can anyone help me with this final steps, please? Thank you in advance.

```
private Image createRGBImageFromGrayPixels_16(int[][] pixels) {
        
        int width = pixels.length;
        int height = pixels[0].length;
        
        BufferedImage bm = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage...); //BufferedImage.TYPE ???

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                
                long rgb = pixels[y][x];
                rgb = (rgb << 16) + pixels[y][x]; 
                rgb = (rgb << 16) + pixels[y][x];
                
                System.out.println(pixels[y][x] + "\t->\t" + rgb);
                System.out.println();
                
                bm.setRGB(x, y, rgb); //ERROR: long type for rgb is not accepted!
            }
        }
        
        Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bm, null);
        
        return img;
    }
```

If needed, I can also install external jar libraries (obviously, only if opersource) that can help me achieving this goal.

Comment: Display? You cannot do it. No screen can handle 16-bit per channel, so do not expect much support. Many graphical programs support 16bit per channel, but as internal representation (useful for calculation without losing much data). Note: often linear RGB with half precision floats.

Comment: What a pity @GiacomoCatenazzi, I wasn't aware about this fact. 
So, I suppose I'll have to give up and simply use images with 8bit per channel.. Thank you

Comment: Some professional screens can do 10-bit or 12-bit per channel, but usually with poor software support (but within professional programs) (and it is done to keep actual images, and to get extra bits for extra gamut and HDR. In any case, if I remember correctly, we can distinguish (human eye) around 1000 shades of greys (so around 10-bit), and no screens have no good black, so with 8-bit you do not lose much information.

Comment: The conversion "Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bm, null);" would kill all these extra bits anyway, so why bother.

Comment: You can see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20267282/1428606) for how to create an RGB `BufferedImage`with 16 bits per channel (48 bits per pixel). It doesn't make sense to use `setRGB` in this case, as it only supports 8 bits per channel. You need to access the raster/`short` backing array directly. But in any case, I'm afraid @mipa is correct. I don't think JavaFX has support for 16 bits per channel images. It's probably faster/easier to just use a standard type and the upper 8 bits of each channel for a plain 24 bit image.

Comment: Thank you everybody, I just did some toy examples in JavaFX during my university studies and now that I'm working hardly with images and their manipulation to create a software for my thesis, it seems that my knowledge base is actually very poor! Fortunately, there are people like you that share their experience and knowledge for free, so thank you again!